# How to call a javascript function using python script?

Tags: javascript, python

I am doing a web scraping project in which i stumbled upon a web page that has captcha. Now the thing is that the link that captcha is only shown when i hit refresh captcha button, which is in fact a  java-script function called refresh capthca.
Here is the code of button :

```
     <a title="Request a new validation code." href="javascript: refreshCaptcha();"      onclick="#">
     <img src="index.jpg" border="0" style="vertical-align:bottom;" width="23" height="22"></a>
```

How to call that function or click on that refresh captcha button using python script?

Comment: where is the code of button ?

Comment: are you using scrapy? if not I recommend using it

Comment: I am using Beautiful Soup for scraping purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have [`node`](http://nodejs.org/) installed you can use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module

```
from subprocess import call
call(['node', '-e', 'JavaScript', 'code', 'here'])
```